# Sensitivity of Initialization Values for an Optimization Algorithm

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I am interested using Gradient Based Optimization Algorithms (e.g. BFGS) for optimizing the *Rastrign Function* (over the range of (0,0) to (5,5)):

[image]

```
 Rastrigin <- function(x)
    {
        return(20 + x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x[1]) + cos(2*pi*x[2])))
    }
```

**Note: the real minimum is (0,0)**

I tried to do this using the R programming language, and noticed that the "initial values" can result in different outcomes. For example:

**Attempt #1 : (Start with (2,2)**

```
optim(par = c(2,2), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")


$par
[1] 5.453531e-15 5.453531e-15

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       7        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

**Attempt #2 : Start with (0,0)**

```
 optim(par = c(0,0), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 0 0

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

**Attempt 3: Start with (4.9, 4.9)**

```
optim(par = c(4.9, 4.9), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 4.974691 4.974691

$value
[1] 49.74745

$counts
function gradient 
       5        5 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

**Attempt 4: Start with (0.01, 0.01)**

```
optim(par = c(0.01, 0.01), Rastrigin, lower = c(-5,-5), upper = c(5,5), method = "L-BFGS-B")
$par
[1] 1.813333e-11 1.813333e-11

$value
[1] 0

$counts
function gradient 
       6        6 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

As we can see, sometimes the choice of initial values can heavily throw the optimization algorithm away from the correct results. For instance, in **Attempt 3** convergence was reached, but a value of `49.74745` was returned instead of 0.

**My Question:** Is there a general consensus on how to select the initial values for an optimization algorithm?

In my case, the function being optimized only has 2 dimensions and we already know the true minimum value. Suppose if the function had many dimensions and we did not know the true value - how could we have selected the initial values for the optimization algorithm?

My naïve attempt would have been select the midpoint between the min/max range over which the function is being optimized. For example, if a 5 dimensional function is being optimized over (0,0,0,0,0) and (5,5,5,5,5) - I would have selected (5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2, 5-0/2) has the initial value for the optimization algorithm.

**How are initial values generally chosen for optimization algorithms and why are they so important?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule that helps you select a “good” starting value. Choosing the mid-point is probably the most obvious choice at the beginning. And if you use “standard” benchmark functions you will notice that the mid-point is very often a *very* good choice (see, for example, http://infinity77.net/go_2021/scipy_extended.html).

For a real-life or non-benchmark problems though, it is not that easy. If you insist on using local optimization algorithms, your best bet is to multi-start them, I.e., run BFGS from many different starting points and see which one gives you the lowest value for your objective function. That said, BFGS is a local optimization algorithm and it will only ever guarantee a local minimum.

Alternatively, you may want to explore the features of global optimization solvers (simulated annealing, genetic/evolutionary algorithms, multilevel coordinates search, etc…) that are able to explore the parameter space more widely irrespectively of the starting point. Those algorithms are however generally slower to converge to an optimum, but they guarantee a better exploration of the parameters space.

No algorithm will 100% of the times give you the global optimum, no matter whether you’re looking at benchmark problems or real-life optimizations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!